# How to modify the content of popup page in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple Chrome extension that has a button in the popup window, and when the user clicks that button, some text in that popup changes. Here is what I have:

`popup.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button id="myButton">Button</button>
    <p id="myText">hello</p>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js` file:

```js
let myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},  // This is probably wrong???
    function: doSomething,
  });
});

function doSomething() {
  console.log("button is clicked");
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHtml = "foo bar";
}
```

I am able to see "button is clicked" in the console, but do not see the content of popup change from "hello" to "foo bar". I suspect this is because the target I used in `executeScript` is wrong, but I am not sure what's the right way to fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't use chrome.scripting.executeScript, it's for web pages. Just call doSomething directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "foo bar";
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("myText").innerHtml = "foo bar";
```

Comment: Ah, silly me.. Thanks!

Comment: Quick followup, changing `innerHtml` to `innerHTML` does work (the text in popup.html changed), but I also got `VM139:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')` from console. Any thought why that is the case?

Comment: Is the popup.js loading before mytext element?